# Searching by 'Contribution Source' gives no results CiviCRM 5.21.1

Tags: contributions

I currently cannot search using the 'Contribution Source' field within advanced search. I can however use the field successfully within the 'Find contributions' search.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work ok on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and 5.23. I know there were a lot of search form changes around 5.21/5.22. If you're able to upgrade it seems to be working.